# Nginx 403 Forbidden for location and localhost

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, nginx-location, ubuntu-20.04

My target is to access to a specific location (i.e. phpmyadmin) using an SSH tunnel http://localhost/phpmyadmin

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 with Nginx. The following configuration was working fine with Ubuntu 18.04.

I edited /etc/nginx/sites-available/default adding:

```
  location /phpmyadmin {
    #Allow localhost
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    #deny all the others ip
    deny all;
  }
```

when I access to http://localhost/phpmyadmin I receive the error message:

> 403 Forbidden nginx/1.17.10 (Ubuntu)

Just for testing I have removed "deny all;" everything it is working fine, but every ip address can access the location phpmyadmin.

error log nginx:

> 2020/05/05 23:52:13 [error] 21905#21905: *1 access forbidden by rule, client: ::1, server: _, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

   # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }


location /phpmyadmin {
    satisfy all;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
    }


   }
```

Any idea why this configuration is not working anymore with ubuntu 20.04 and nginx 1.17.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow ::1 too...
And add the parameters for the php inside the location block too.

Try like this

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

   # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }


    location ^~ /phpmyadmin/ {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can I see your entire vhost?

Comment: I have added the full configuration to the vhost. When I remove "deny all" it is working.

Comment: try change the location to ```location ^~ /phpmyadmin```

Comment: still nothing. I have tries with another location:     `location ^~ /test {
  satisfy all; #requires both conditions
        allow 127.0.0.1; #allow localhost only
        deny all; #deny all other sources
    }` but still the same result.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but are you reload or restart the nginx? Whats the result of `nginx -t`

Comment: that is fine. Yes, I reload and restart the service as well. I have even installed again ubuntu 20.04 and nginx only, but I have got the same result.

Comment: I`ll provide a helpful test later... Sorry for can't help at moment

Comment: I saw in the log the clien ip, `... access forbidden by rule, client: ::1, ...`, and you need to allow ::1 and add the php parameters

Comment: @Steve Did you test again?

Comment: The solution you have proposed it is working fine! The solution was to add the line `allow ::1;`. Thank you.